# Cannot access Zip File located in Assets folder in Windows Runtime Apps

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-8.1

I'm trying to get the zip file that is located inside the Assets folder of  Solution Explorer with the following code. It works well for other types of file like: .txt, .jpg, .png. But it gives error when trying to get the zip file. `The system cannot find the file specified.`

```
var zipFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("Assets\\Test.zip");
```

Comment: Accessing Assets folder in code will be bit difficult may be for application security model. mark the file as content and try this code instead if it helps:
`var zipFile = StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new System.Uri(@"Assets\\Test.zip", System.UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: I had tried that but didn't work. Now I got its solution below. Thanks you so much @Kiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip files aren't included in the appx package by default (.txt, .jpg, and .png are). Select your file in the solution explorer, look at the zip file's properties, and make sure the build action is set to "Content" so that the file will be included in the Appx:
[image: Build action: Content pane (with obligatory red arrows)]

You can confirm that the file was (or was not) copied to the Appx after deploying from Visual Studio by looking in the (by default) \bin\x86\Release\AppX\Assets directory (or whichever architecture and configuration you deployed).

Comment: Wow. This is life saving. Thank you so much @Rob.