# How to directly open file from a button click?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I am working on an UWP app, on VisualStudio in C#.

I would like to know how to simply open a file on UWP. The files would be either Excel or word files. And those files are on a public server

The pméy solution I have is:

`private void G_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{ StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Me/Desktop")};`

But it doesn't let me link a path to a server (Like T:/...)
(Plus I can't open the file directly by clicking on it, I have to right click > Open with > Excel. Otherwise nothing happens)

So my question is, can I directly link the file to open it directly? If so, how?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the default program of the file type (ex.: .docx for Word), you can try to use [Launcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher#methods) class with LaunchFileAsync method. Get files on WinRT is a little bit different, you can try register your app to access some know folders (ex.: Downloads, Documents, Videos, etc) or create a [FileOpenPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker) dialog to get any file from the file system letting user to choose what file would like to open.

Comment: I will try the luncher class. I could use the FileOpenPicker dialog indeed but I don't want the user to go and search for the file. I'd like to link the button to the path of my file and simply open it when the button clicked...

Comment: @CeeTee You can try to get a StorageFolder object from an absolute path with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfolderfrompathasync) and create a button for each file maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the UWP file access permission limitation, you cannot access files directly from disk. For more details about the file access permission, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions). If you want to access specific file, you can use broadfilesystemaccess and openfilepicker.

About [broadfilesystemaccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations), you need to add **broadFileSystemAccess** capability and allow your app to access file system in Settings. In that case, you can directly access file from disk using Storagefile API with path.

And about [FileOpenPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers), it will open a dialog that similar to file explorer, then you could choose the file from the location you want and use it in your app.

**Update:**

If you want to directly open the specific file by clicking on the button, you can try to use LaunchFileAsync. More details about LaunchFileAsync, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-the-default-app-for-a-file). In addition, if you put your excel or word file directly into you project, you need to notice that “xlsx or docx files aren't included in the appx package by default (.txt, .jpg, and .png are)". So please select your excel or word file in the solution explorer, look at the Build Action in properties below, make sure it is set to **"Content"**. In that case, you can launch the file. You can refer this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010421/cannot-access-zip-file-located-in-assets-folder-in-windows-runtime-apps) to set.

Comment: Alright thank you, I will try that and let you know if I found the solution

Comment: I did use FileOpenPicker. It kinda works; though I'd like to link the button to the path of my file and simply open it when the button clicked. It doesn't seem that complicated but I can't do it :(

Comment: Do you mean you want to directly use the file path to find the file? And the broadFileSystemAccess can't help you to achieve this effect?

Comment: I'd like to open an excel or a word file by clicking on a button on my app or, if this is too complicated, open an explorer window on the folder of the file and open it.

Comment: If you want to directly open the specific file by clicking on the button, you can try to use LaunchFileAsync. But you need to add broadFileSystemAccess capability first to access the specific path. More details about LaunchFileAsync, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-the-default-app-for-a-file).

Comment: I can't do it, even with the documents you linked me... I'm sorry I'm a beginner. I really can't open any file from my app, even if the file is in my PC or "installed" in my app files. Can't use LaunchFileAsync...

Comment: Alright I managed to do it with an image. Using the code refrenced in your link. Still can't do it with a word or an excel... Any advice?

Comment: Here's where it stops: #if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Comment: Do you put your excel or word file directly into you project and follow the link to try to open the file? You need to notice that “xlsx or docx files aren't included in the appx package by default (.txt, .jpg, and .png are)". So please select your excel or word file in the solution explorer, look at the Build Action in properties below, make sure it is set to **"Content"**. In that case, you can launch the file. You can refer this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010421/cannot-access-zip-file-located-in-assets-folder-in-windows-runtime-apps) to set.

Comment: YES! It works now! Had to set the propreties to content indeed! Thank you!!